# Add RPC features to Bernstein's Daemontools

Tags: rpc

I'm a Computer Science student from Italy, I have to do a project based on a **modified** version of the Daemontools Of D.J. Bernstein which has to implement remote procedure calls under Unix.

Normally to get a daemon up with the tools I use this syntax:

```
svc -u /service/NameOfDaemon
```

And down with this:

```
svc -d /service/NameOfDaemon
```

So I can control a daemon locally. The idea is to add a block of code to be able to control a daemon situated on a remote machine, this will be the ideal syntax:

```
svc -u IP/service/NameOfDaemon
```

where IP stands for the actual IP of the target machine, known by the user.

In these days I googled and learned about RPC and DTools but I am a bit stuck, can anyone help me get started?

Perhaps also some recommended reading for my project?

Comment: If you're doing this under the direction of someone, ask them what resources you should be looking at. Otherwise this belongs on a site like Unix&Linux.SE

Answer (score 2):

The unix way of doing this is to say:

```
ssh -n root@remotehost svc -u /service/NameOfDaemon
```

The [unix philosophy](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html) is about creating small tools which do one thing well, and work together with other tools. `svc` is a tool which can control daemons on the local machine. `ssh` can run tools on remote machines. There is no need for another tool.

If you absolutely must have a single command which can control both local and remote daemons, then as Chris suggests, you can write a shell script which runs `svc` or `ssh` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`supervise` uses Unix-domain sockets to receive requests. The advantage of using Unix-domain sockets is that access to it can be controlled via the usual filesystem permissions---in this case, it allows only root to access the socket, hence the reason why you normally must run `svc` as root.

However, once you go over the network, you start having to think about network authentication (unless you want any Tom, Dick, and Harry to start and stop your services). If you can solve that, the rest of it is easy:

- Write a service that runs over `tcpserver`, that can invoke `svc` on the remote machine for you. If the access control provided by `tcpserver` is sufficient for you, then well and good; otherwise your service must handle what's left.

  - To be secure, don't run this service as root (i.e., always specify `-u` on the `tcpserver` command line). Instead, just change the (group) ownership of your `supervise` sockets so that they are readable and writeable by the user that your service runs as.
- Write a shell script on the client side that wraps around `svc`. It checks for the "remote server" syntax and if used, it would connect to your remote service (and otherwise just invoke `svc` as usual).

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the answers   Ok understood what you are saying and it's certainly the easy and the right way to have control to a remote machine, but in my project it's requested to really add some code in the supervice.c or svc.c file. Then to recompile all the Tools to get a modified version of them which are able to implement also a remote invocation of `svc -u` command...It's hard and not so useful but this is the project that I'm called to do so I have to follow these specs...